# How to restrict user to a particular folder in CentOS 6?

Tags: permissions, centos6, user-permissions

I will need to create users so developers can log in and clone/pull/push changes/repositories from a github like platform.

I've managed to add a user (using the root) to this CentOS machine; I now have this line in /etc/passwd:

```
chris:x:32008:32010::/home/chris/public_html:/bin/bash
```

..and this in /etc/shadow:

```
chris:$1$ruUeLtTu$onAY2hdu1J.UmHajEIlmR.:15385:0:99999:7:::
```

I am able to SSH the server, I have permission to create a folder and I guess that should be enough. But I am able to see other files and folders outside public_html.

**How can I** actually **restrict the user to a particular directory** so he can't "cd out" of his folder?

Update:

```
root@echo [~]# ls -ld /home/moove
drwx--x--x 21 moove moove 4096 Mar 22 16:16 /home/moove/
root@echo [~]# ls -ld /home/moove/public_html
drwxr-x--- 11 moove nobody 4096 Mar 27 11:29 /home/moove/public_html/
root@echo [~]# ls -ld /home/moove/public_html/dev
drwxr-x--- 12 moove nobody 4096 Mar 27 14:47 /home/moove/public_html/dev/
root@echo [~]# ls -ld /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal
drwxr-xr-x 3 arsenal moove 4096 Mar 27 14:53 /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal/
```

Comment: Do you want this user to have an interactive shell or just use sftp to transfer files ?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me @Iain, however, cjc's answer helped me and it seems to work! Out of curiosity, I don't know what you mean by "interactive shell"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chroot them, but that leads to complications and additional setup.

If you don't need to fully chroot, you can try using the restricted shell function in bash.

```
RESTRICTED SHELL
       If  bash  is  started  with  the name rbash, or the -r option is supplied at invocation, the
       shell becomes restricted.  A restricted shell is used to set up  an  environment  more  con-
       trolled than the standard shell.  It behaves identically to bash with the exception that the
       following are disallowed or not performed:

       ·      changing directories with cd
       ·      setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV
       ·      specifying command names containing /
       ·      specifying a file name containing a / as an argument to the .  builtin command
       ·      Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the  hash
              builtin command
       ·      importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup
       ·      parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup
       ·      redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators
       ·      using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with another command
       ·      adding  or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin
              command
       ·      Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins
       ·      specifying the -p option to the command builtin command
       ·      turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted.

       These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.
```

To implement this, create a link between /bin/rbash and /bin/bash (because CentOS doesn't ship with this link by default): `ln /bin/bash /bin/rbash`.  Then change /etc/passwd so that the user's shell is `/bin/rbash`.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you very much. Why would I need to fully chroot it, is this if they user will want more rights and access to more commands? Later edit: I'vr finally read what you wrote about Restricted Shell and there's no need for another answer, everything is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: chroot would imply boxing the user into a tiny replica of the root filesystem, from which they cannot exit.  You would have greater control over what they can do, but you would need a greater amount of configuration to get it to work as expected.  This would provide greater control over the user's behavior.

Comment: Quick question, is there anyway I can chmod that home directory by default somehow? I am getting this after login: `Could not chdir to home directory /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal: Permission denied`.

Comment: @ChrisDemetriad, it's hard to know what permissions are needed, but the chmod would need to be run by a non-rbash user, i.e., done before login.

Comment: I understand that and it makes sense. An example of how would I accomplish that? I am still searching for a better written article that would help me understand and had no success yet, for the last half an hour. I only need a hint, a keyword, and I will take it from there. I know it must be something like `chmod -R 755 /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal` but to give "arsenal" user rights to that folder, right?

Comment: I have tried `chown arsenal /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal/` as root but I get the same error after I log in with the new created user 'arsenal'.

Comment: @ChrisDemetriad Update your question with the output from the following commands: `ls -ld /home/moove`, `ls -ld /home/moove/public_html`, `ls -ld /home/moove/public_html/dev` and `ls -ld /home/moove/public_html/dev/arsenal/`.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Try `chmod +x /home/moove/public_html /home/moove/public_html/dev`

Comment: Thank you very much, and have a great day/night. I'm researching about owners permissions right now so I will be able to sort out these things myself in the future.